# Why are some questions highlighted with a blue (now yellow) background?

Tags: support, questions

When I am viewing a list of questions of DA, some have a while background and some a blue. I thought that it may be a zebra effect but it isn't. I can't quite work out the logic behind why a questions is one color or another.

This must be obvious but I can't work it out.

I have ruled out

- Asker Reputation
- Presence of an answer
- Presence of an accepted answer
- Votes on question
- SO migration (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlighted questions are those that are using one of the tags you have in your "Favorite tags" list.

[image: screenshot]

If you don't have any favorite tags, the SE software automatically select some questions basing on the questions you answered or the questions you have seen, and on the tags used by those questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is questions tagged with your "Frequented tags" that are listed at the top right of http://drupal.stackexchange.com.